# EF Core: Access value conversion result in ValueGenerator

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I want to autogenerate some hash on add/update each time a specific property in my entity changes. The property has conversion (to JSON string). I want to access the **converted** value of that property and calculate its hash in my value generator. E.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(
            b =>
            {
                b.Property(x => x.MyCollection)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, default(JsonSerializerOptions)),
                        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyCollectionItem[]>(v, default(JsonSerializerOptions))
                             ?? Array.Empty<MyCollectionItem>())
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'[]'");
b.Property(x => x.MyHash)
.HasValueGenerator<MyHashValueGenerator>().ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

The current implementation is something like:

```
class MyHashValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<string>
{
    public override string Next(EntityEntry entry)
     => CalculateHash(JsonSerializer.Serialize((entry.Entity as MyEntity).Cells(), default(JsonSerializerOptions)));
    
    override public bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;
}
```

Here serialization happens twice: as part of conversion and during value generation. Can I access the converted value directly in value generator ?